# Which email message would it be preferable to send to my coworker, who has a cold?

Tags: word-choice, email

Which of these messages would be most suitable?

> 1. I'm feeling so sorry for you. I hope you will take good care of yourself.
> 2. I am sorry to hear you are sick. Please get better soon.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! Please read our help about [what's on-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [on asking questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This question relies on the culture of your office, which we don't know; it's writing advice, which is off-topic; and everyone's opinion is equally valid -- there is no correct answer. But do stick around and have a look at highly-upvoted questions to find the sort of questions which do fit on this site.

Comment: the first one is too "personal". use the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first variant sounds a little warmer and more personal. The second one has a more formal tone. So your choice will probably depend mostly on how emotionally close you are to your coworker.

Comment: Thank you for all and I apologize to ask such a personal topic.
We each are not so close so I have chosen second phrase.
Thank you kind answer.